# Extending lines to edge of polygon, but not where start/end point intersects another line

Tags: line, fme-form, fme-transformer

I have made center line dataset from polygons. However, at the endpoints these lines didn't extend to the edge of the polygons.

[image]

So I used the FME line extender tool, to extend the lines by large distance, then clipped them with the polygon layer grouped by a shared id. This fixed the issue at end points

[image]

But it also led to the unwanted side effect at intersections of lines within a polygon.

Before:

[image]

after:

[image]

I am looking for a way to avoid extending lines, at locations where the start or end points are at the intersection of another line

I am wanting an FME or QGIS solution

Comment: By the way: when adding screenshots (and even more so when creating a map), use colors with high contrast. The colors you use for polygons and lines are hard to distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. I am new to FME so excuse my termonology

1. intersect tool with extended lines and original lines
2. Line on line overlay with intersected layer and original lines.
3. Extension only sections of lines can be extracted with overlay count attribute from line on line (overlap = 1)
4. Extract end points from original lines
5. pointonpoint overlay to count overlapping vertex
6. Join point to extended only lines
7. extract only lines where vertex count is less than 2
8. merge cleaned extensions with original lines

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, this might be more complicated a solution in FME than I'd like. Here's a solution that gets us 90% of the way - but the last 10% I just can't see.

Firstly, we need to know whether the end of a line connects with another. You could do this a couple of ways. You could use a TopologyBuilder transformer and figure it out with that information.

Alternatively, I used a Snipper to get endpoints and then two SpatialRelator transformers. The first counts the number of line overlaps for each point. The second transfers those values to each line as a list.

[image]

Now each line has a list of the number of times it matches at each end:

[image]

At one end there is only a single match, (related_suppliers = 1) so we know that can be extended. The other end has more matches (related_suppliers = 3) so we know that connects and should not be extended.

Now you can put down a LineExtender. You would keep either the Beginning or End outputs depending on what the values on the list were.

But... the problem I haven't solved yet is that we don't know whether the "1" value refers to the start or the end of the line. It doesn't seem to be consistent. So you don't really know which end of the line to extend. That's going to be the last 10% of the workspace, and it might be the hardest!

Anyway, I hope what I put here helps you get some way along the path to the solution that you need. You can [find my workspace here](https://github.com/FMEEvangelist/FMECommunity/raw/main/SupportFiles/Overlaps.fmwt).

Answer (score 1):

Was searching for the same solution and found an easier way than mentioned above. If each polygon has a unique ID (or create one if necessary) prior to creating the centreline then the centreline and the polygon will both have the same unique ID. Then run the clipper and group on the unique ID. Should work.